# i try to put this css code to the elementor for background animated gradient but effect dont appear is please watch these short video for uderstand

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

This is complete code
[image]
[this is class so i enter something in this][this is youtube video link this excatly i try to doing so please watch this video for better uderstanding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMsQyixG3Sg)

[image]

i try to make background gradient so please solve this issue to understand what problem please watch this complete youtube video

Comment: We can’t tell why your actual code isn’t working if we can’t see it. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score -1):

Please replace the "css-selector" with other class name (example : mycontainer), or just use selector like what the tutorial video show you then your code will work. Elementor might take the "selector" as the element specific class name like what we do in custom css thus your code won't work.